# I made a register form for my site but when I run it and you press enter on the last box(the email box) it doesnt submit the info

Tags: php, html, forms, dreamweaver

So I am making a site on dreamweaver and I cant figure out on my register page how to make it so when you press enter on the last box you need to fill in (email box) that it will automatically submit the info... instead it just deletes the stuff in that box... The only way to submit it is by actually pressing the submit button... anybody know how to do this? Thanks alot

Comment: Show us your code so we can see what's causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a tab order issue to me,  make sure the submit is in the tab order right after the last input box.   Also, you could do as the other suggested and use javascript to fire submit form event when the enter button is pressed.